# iOS unpausing game after didBecomeActive

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Sometime ago I was having a problem with pausing my game when `didBecomeActive`, then I found a solution which I thought was working, until now.
I found out that iOS automatically pauses my game (all of it) when I leave, not terminate, a game; and when coming back (`didBecomeActive`), it unpauses. As my point was to pause a singular layer (`gameLayer`), I created a boolean variable and an if condition to check if my game is paused or not.

If `checkPause == false` (**not paused**) -> it'll call a pausing function (that works great) when coming back to the game (moments after?! being unpaused by the system)

If `checkPause == true` (**paused**) -> it'll will set `gameLayer.paused = false` (unpaused by the system) to `true` (once it was paused before leaving the game)

Basically `gameLayer` is not being paused when coming back. It looks like iOS unpauses my game after `didBecomeActive` function.

I made an example project with it's code below (it's all commented and the simplest it could get)

If you want, you can download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mhwwp6aygcd09cw/AADeR7HheQKFtk6YKGphlNwWa?dl=0).

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //Declarations
    var gameLayer = SKNode()
    var pauseLayer = SKNode()

    var checkPause = Bool() //checkPause == true -> gameLayer is paused | checkPause == false -> gameLayer is not paused

    var enemy = SKSpriteNode()

    var pauseButton = SKSpriteNode()
    var playButton = SKSpriteNode()



    //"Cage" objects in the screen
    func cageObjects(){

        //"caging" every object
        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
    }

    //Setup
    func setupPauseButton(){

        //Pause
        pauseButton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "pause")
        pauseButton.setScale(1)
        pauseButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 1.2)
    }
    func setupPlayButton(){

        //Play
        playButton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
        playButton.setScale(1)
        playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 1.2)
    }
    func setupEnemy(){

        //Enemy
        enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
        enemy.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 1, self.frame.height / 2)
        enemy.name = "enemy"
        enemy.setScale(0.5)

        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }

    //Layers
    func createGameLayer(){

        //pauseButton
        setupPauseButton()
        gameLayer.addChild(pauseButton) //add pauseButton to gameLayer
    }
    func createPauseLayer(){

        //playButton
        setupPlayButton()
        pauseLayer.addChild(playButton) //add playButton to pauseLayer
    }

    //Spawn
    func spawnEnemy(){

        //Start spawning, moving and removing
        let spawnEnemy = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            //Spawn enemy
            self.setupEnemy()
            self.gameLayer.addChild(self.enemy)

            //Move left and remove when go off screen
            let frameWidth = CGFloat(self.frame.width)
            let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveByX(-frameWidth - 50, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.0028 * frameWidth)) //duration: faster or slower
            let removeEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            var moveAndRemove = SKAction()
            moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, removeEnemy])

            self.enemy.runAction(moveAndRemove)
        })

        //Spawn enemy each 2 seconds
        let spawnEnemyDuration = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([spawnEnemy, SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)]))
        gameLayer.runAction(spawnEnemyDuration)
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        print ("didMoveToView")

        registerAppTransitionObservers()

        cageObjects()

        checkPause = false

        createGameLayer()
        createPauseLayer()

        self.addChild(gameLayer)

        spawnEnemy()
    }

    //Game states
    func pauseState(){

        //Pause game
        pauseButton.hidden = true //hide pauseButton
        gameLayer.paused = true //pause gameLayer
        checkPause = true //game is paused

        self.addChild(pauseLayer) //add pauseLayer
    }
    func playState(){

        pauseLayer.removeFromParent() //remove pauseLayer

        //Resume game
        checkPause = false //game is not paused
        gameLayer.paused = false //unpause gameLayer
        pauseButton.hidden = false //show pauseButton
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        //When touch buttons/screen
        for touch in touches{

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

            if node == pauseButton{
                pauseState()
            }
            else if node == playButton{
                playState()
            }
        }
    }



    //Functions from AppDelegate
    func registerAppTransitionObservers(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    //Just launched
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(){
        print("DidBecomeActive")

        //gameLayer unpausing problem solving attempt
        if checkPause == true{
            gameLayer.paused = true
        }
        //Pause when game is not paused and user leave the screen OR when game is launched
        else if checkPause == false{
            pauseState()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have your source, I see your problem.

You need to preserve your pause state:

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
    ...
    override var paused: Bool
    {
        get{
            return super.paused;
        }
        set{
            let value = self.gameLayer.paused
            super.paused = newValue;
            self.gameLayer.paused = value;

        }

    }
}
```

For some reason, scene paused is deciding to unpause all nodes under it

Also, you should pause your game when you leave the app, not when you come back.

```
//Functions from AppDelegate
func registerAppTransitionObservers(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.applicationWillResign), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

func applicationWillResign(){
    print("WillResignActive")
    pauseState()
}
```

And you can get rid of that check paused variable,  that is redundant bloat code.

Comment: By the way, I basically copied/pasted, because I don't know (yet) what these get/set do, but I'll certainly look up (now).

Comment: it is called properties,  the paused variable in your scene is a property because the real variable is located at SKNode, so essentially what GameScene.paused really is is `var paused: Bool
    {
        get{
            return super.paused;
        }
        set{
            super.paused = newValue;
     
        }

    }` Which tells the super class that we are changing the value.  What I am doing is preserving the pause state of the gameLayer, since somewhere along the hierarchy (SKNode) the paused property is going to all of the children and unpausing it,

Comment: which it really shouldn't, but that may be how swift pauses and unpauses all the nodes, instead of doing a check on the parent (grandparent) only

Comment: So you are changing `gameLayer.paused` value back to `true`(?!) after iOS changes `super.paused` (which changes all `.paused` values??) value?

Comment: Then I understood!! Thank you again =)